# How to declare a class based on type of another class

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an instance of a templated class, based on the template type of another class. But I am getting the following error.

`error: template argument 1 is invalid`

Here is a minimal example to reproduce the error

```
template <typename IdType>
class GraphNode
{
    IdType id;
};

template <typename IdType>
class Graph
{
public:
    using NodeType = IdType;

    GraphNode<IdType> nodes[100];
};

template <typename IdType>
class ProcessGraph
{
    //some functions
};

template <typename IdType>
auto create_graph()
{
    Graph<IdType> graph;
    // populate graph here
    return graph;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(atoi(argv[1]))
        const auto &graph = create_graph<int>();
    else
        const auto &graph = create_graph<unsigned long>();

    auto processor = ProcessGraph<typename graph.NodeType>(); // The error occurs here
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. The `graph` variable has a different type in the branches, and it is out of scope when declaring `processor`.
2. The syntax to access an inner type alias is wrong.

---

You can retrieve the type of a variable `x` using `decltype(x)`. Since `graph` is a reference, you need to remove the reference using `std::remove_reference_t`. Afterwards, you can use `::NodeType` to retrieve the inner type alias.

```
if(atoi(argv[1]))
{
    const auto &graph = create_graph<int>();
    auto processor = ProcessGraph<
        std::remove_reference_t<decltype(graph)>::NodeType>();
}
else
{
    const auto &graph = create_graph<unsigned long>();
    auto processor = ProcessGraph<
        std::remove_reference_t<decltype(graph)>::NodeType>();
}
```

If you want to refactor the code to avoid repetition, place the code that initializes the `processor` variable in a `template` function that gets `graph` as a parameter *(or that creates `graph` in its body with a user-defined type)*.

Comment: Thanks. They problem 1 was created while creating the minimal example. I think the error was with the 2nd point